# UISelector.text() different behavior between OS versions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-uiautomator

I have found some weird behavior regarding UiAutomator's `UISelector.text()` method.

Let's take this sample code:

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName).depth(0)), 1000)

device.findObject(UiSelector().text("Some text"))
```

And suppose I have a `Button` in my first activity that looks like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/my_button_height"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textAllCaps
        />
```

When trying to target buttons with properties like `textAllCaps` the behavior of this method changes depending on the Android version of the device.

For android versions `Nougat` (api level 24) or higher, this method expects the string passed as parameter to be in caps, as it is rendered (e.g. `"SOME TEXT"`), while for lower versions it expects the string to be the text assigned to that button's `android:text` attribute.

Has anyone come up with this? How do you write UITests that run for every android version (let's say `minSDKVersion = 19`)?

(I know I can use `UISelector.description()` and `UISelector.resourceId()` but I would like to be able to use `UISelector.text()` when desired)